# ARM Cortex M4F Undefined reference to printf

Tags: c, arm, printf, bare-metal

Basically I want to use the stdio functions such as printf, puts, scanf, etc, to print either on my 16x2 LCD Display or through the serial port or I2C port or whatever I want.

I'm using the arm-none-eabi compiler and newlib. In my research I've found that I have to implement the **read** and **write** Supporting OS Subroutines, which has sense since there is not underlying OS who implements the stdin and stdout.

> If some of these subroutines are not provided with your system—in the extreme case, if you are developing software for a “bare board” system, without an OS—you will at least need to provide do-nothing stubs (or subroutines with minimal functionality) to allow your programs to link with the subroutines in libc.a.
>   https://sourceware.org/newlib/

So, the question is where I have to define or redefine these subroutines? because I tried to do it in a random file and all that I get is this compilation error

```
undefined reference to `puts'
```

And when I look forward into the newlib files all that I could find so far is this paragraph in the stdio.h file

```
typedef int cookie_close_function_t(void *__cookie);
typedef struct
{
/* These four struct member names are dictated by Linux; hopefully,
they don't conflict with any macros.  */
  cookie_read_function_t  *read;
  cookie_write_function_t *write;
  cookie_seek_function_t  *seek;
  cookie_close_function_t *close;
} cookie_io_functions_t;
```

Finally, this is how I'm using the compiler, maybe I'm missing something or maybe there is a wrong flag.

```
arm-none-eabi-gcc -o build/dummy.o src/dummy.c -g -mthumb -mcpu=cortex-m4 -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -mfloat-abi=softfp -Os -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -MD -std=c99 -Wall -pedantic -DPART_tm4c123gh6pm -c -I./inc -I/home/user/lib/TivaWare -DTARGET_IS_BLIZZARD_RA1

arm-none-eabi-ld -o build/a.out build/blink.o build/startup_gcc.o build/uart.o -T tm4c123gh6pm.ld --entry ResetISR --gc-sections
```

PD: I assume that the C library is linked by default, if I explicitly add the -lc option the ld command as suggested by several people around there, then I get this error:

```
arm-none-eabi-ld: cannot find -lc
```

Comment: In ARM GCC it is not linked by default and does not "just work". You need actual function to read/write from/to streams. I've provided examples but are not for GCC. Or maybe could work there. Check for STM32F4-Discovery.net printf.

Comment: I could be wrong, but you may have to define `__write` in `write.c`, or the equivalent for GCC. I'm using IAR.

Comment: printf support us relatively massive, better off avoiding it, but if you have to take newlib and fill in the backend which is relatively easy, make most of the functions return pass, and deal with the write and maybe istty and some others.  then direct the output to your lcd.  easier to start with the lcd side and a send it one character thing, then wrap printf around it.

Comment: or there are some lightweight (like a couple hundred lines) printfs around that are just enough probably for what you want to do and dont have the heavy layers of C libraries on the backend like a real printf.

Comment: I have not done in in a while but the last time a couple years ago was the same as 10+ years ago.  I think the files are system.c and libcfunc.c or something like that that they are in the same directory, grep for _sbrk or _exit for that matter, I prefer to just take the guts out of all the functions, return pass, then figure out the minimum needed for printf to work and so long as it all compiles and fits in your flash, then it will just work for you.

Comment: tilz0R, yes is what I'm trying to do, define the write and read subroutines that supposedly will redirect the stdout and stdin, for the moment just dummy functions. I know it is possible using another compilers like Keil and TI CCS, IAR, compilers specially designed to deal with libc and uC but you know, I want to be done in GCC =P

Comment: old_timer yes I'm using just dummy functions to deal with compilation problems first, then I will look forward on how those functions will actually write bytes on the desired devices . Another thing is, I'm not using the standard libc, I'm using newlib which is intended for uC

Comment: I was talking specifically about newlib.

Comment: newlib/libc/sys/arm/libcfunc.c syscalls.c, syscalls.c  in particular.

Comment: For newlib, you have to retarget/add these functions:
`int _write (int fd, char *ptr, int len)` and `int _read(int fd, char *ptr, int len)`
Also, you may need to add this to your link flag `LNKFLAGS += -specs=nano.specs` to link against Newlib, mini C lib. I hope this works with you!